# Authorization by Role/Group in ASP.NET using Auth0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, jwt, auth0

Thanks in advance for your help in this matter!

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to authorize API access by Group assigned in the Auth0 Authorization extension.

I currently am using the [Authorize] attribute in the web api perfectly - it allows an api call if they have signed in successfully and blocks it if not.

However, if I try [Authorize(Roles = "myGroupName")] authorization fails. Same occurs if I add it to the users app_metadata manually in the Users dashboard on the Auth0 website instead of assigning through the extension.

My project is set up by following the Angular Quick Start and Asp.Net Quick Start. My webapiconfig where I validate the token server side is:

```
 class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var clientID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"];
        var clientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientSecret"];

        configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new JsonWebTokenValidationHandler()
        {
            Audience = clientID,
            SymmetricKey = clientSecret
        });

        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: The JsonWebTokenValidationHandler class don't add the Claim roles by default. Look at this thread https://auth0.com/forum/t/how-to-push-claims-to-users-profile-on-auth0-from-asp-net-5-mvc-6/2424/13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Auth0 Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension) extension currently supports authorization decisions through the concept of groups. You can create a group, assign users to that group and that configure an application to only be accessible to user within a specific group. All of this would be handled automatically and any user outside of the application expected groups would be denied complete access.

Your use case is a bit different, but valid nonetheless. You want the groups configured with the extension to be sent along the generated token so that the application itself makes authorization decisions based on those values.

In order for the groups configured within the extension to be sent along in the token, the first thing you need to do is request them. For this, you need to include the `groups` scope when performing the authentication requests.

> Add the user's group membership to the outgoing token (which can be **requested via the OpenID groups scope**);

(emphasis is mine, source: [Authorization Extension Docs](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension#rule-behavior-for-the-authorization-extension), section *Rule Behavior*)

If you request a token using that scope and then decode it in jwt.io, you would get something similar to this (the actual groups would vary by user):

```
{
  "groups": [
    "GROUP-1",
    "GROUP-2"
  ],
  "iss": "https://[tenant].auth0.com/"
}
```

Now, for the validation of this information on the ASP .NET API side. Assuming the sample you're using is this one ([ASP.NET Web API](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-webapi)), the group information contained within the token would be mapped to the following claims:

- Type: `groups` | Value: `GROUP-1`
- Type: `groups` | Value: `GROUP-2`

This happens because of the logic that exists in the `JsonWebToken` class which handles arrays coming from the JWT payload by creating per-value claim that share the same type.

The final part is making sure the `AuthorizeAttribute` checks these claims of type `groups` instead of trying to lookup role claims. You should be able to accomplish this, by changing the `RoleClaimType` constant in the `JsonWebToken` class to have the value `"groups"` instead of `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"`.

Comment: I moved onto not relying on a third party but I appreciate you taking the time to answer. I feel this best addresses multiple aspects of the question asked.

Comment: wanted to add more detail on how to add to request.  this is how I made it work.
// Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {
    auth: {
      params: {scope: 'openid groups'},
    }
  });

Answer (score 2):

Like you certrainly know, the Authorize attribute works using what is in the principal: something that inherits `IPrincipal`. 
In web api, it is even more specific; it is something that inherits `ClaimsPrincipal` (this implements himself `IPrincipal`). 
As you certainly know already, a claim is like a key-value pair. 
The ClaimsPrincipal contains a serie of key-value pairs that are directly taken from the authentication token. This authentication token is issued by the authentication server most of time as JWT (Json Web Token). Most of time as well, the authentication server is using OAuth, like is your case. 
If the user group, that you expect to be the role in your application doesn't work by using the out-of-the-box Authorize attribute, it's because it is not mapped correctly: `Auhtorize` checks the claim with claim type: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` (the "claim type" is the "key" of the key-value pair). That means that if you want your `Authorize` to work, this claim must be valued with the group.
You can do several things to have a clean authorization in your application.

- Make a custom `Authorize` attribute. This `Authorize` attribute would check the role using a different claim type. The claim type that refers to the user group depends on your authentication server. If you don't find what claim type is used for groups in the doc of your authentication server, run your application in debug, and check every claim that is contained in the property `User` of your controller. You will certainly find what the claim type you are interested in.
- Change the setup of your authorization server by redefining the mapping between user information and claims of the token that is produced (in your case, map groups of the user to the claim that has the type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`). Generally, this can be setup per client application or even globally. For example this is the way that must be done if you use an ADFS authentication, AzureAD or WSO2 authentication server (http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/)
- Add an owin middleware to modify the current principal. It will change the current principal by copying the value of the claim that contains groups into the claim type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`. This middleware must be inserted in the flow after the authentication middleware

Answer (score 1):

I have no rights to comment so I'm going to inquire from here. Why are you doing this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "myGroupName")]
```

as far as I remember when I was implementing group based authorization I was still typing

```
[Authorize(Roles = "myRoleName")]
```

Not other way around.

Comment: Hey man no worries - I get the comment thing. I've tried both - manually assigning in the app meta data to role and also using the Authorization extension for groups. Both show up as a "Group" claim when the token is processed using Auth0 however.